# BroadcastReceiver for DATE_CHANGED only works if I set a date in the future

Tags: android

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.receivers.DateChangedReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This only fires off If I go to settings and change the date to a date in the future. Then I go and change the date to a previous date, nothing happens. Then I go to settings again and change the date to another date in the future, it fires off! I am pretty sure this is a bug in Android.

```
public class DateChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private EventBus bus;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("DateChangedReceiver", "Date changed");
        bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        bus.post(new DateChangedEvent());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I was able to get this to work is by changing

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
```

to

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
```

It fires off at a date change and at a time change too.

Comment: how to change the date to create android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED action?

Comment: you are awesome bro :)